# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null - WebSite Project [SignalR]

Tags: signal-processing, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to understand how the **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity** works with Signal Hub.

I'm running signalr using a dictionary in order to store all the userNames and your connectionsIds

My app works fine for the first run, however it breaks after fews seconds later
It gives me a error about HttpContext.Current.User.Identity again.

It returned null to me.

Here is the error that i got:

[image]

Here is my code: [ChatHub]

```
namespace SistemaJaspion.AppCode
{

    [HubName("chatHub")]

    [Authorize]
    public class ContadorHub : Hub
    {

        private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =  new ConnectionMapping<string>();

        string userLogged = new Usuario().ReturnUserId(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)).Nome;

        public void SendChatMessage(string who, string message)
        {
            string name = new Usuario().ReturnUserId(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)).Nome;

            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
            {
                Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
            }
        }


        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            string name = userLogged;
            //string name = new Usuario().ReturnUserId(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)).Nome;

            _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);

            //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in _connections)
            //{
            //    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
            //}

            // Update the number of the connected users

            int totalIndice = _connections.Count;


            Clients.All.reportConnections(_connections.Count);

            string quantidade = "";

            quantidade = _connections.GetAllConnections().ToString();


            //foreach (var  in _connections)
            //{
            //    Debug.Write(value.ToString());
            //}

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            string name = userLogged;
            //string name = new Usuario().ReturnUserId(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)).Nome;

            _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            string name = userLogged;
            //string name = new Usuario().ReturnUserId(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)).Nome;

            if (!_connections.GetConnections(name).Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
            {
                _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
            }

            return base.OnReconnected();
        }
    }


    //Testing

    public class ConnectionMapping<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections =  new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _connections.Count;
            }
        }


        public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    connections = new HashSet<string>();
                    _connections.Add(key, connections);
                }

                lock (connections)
                {
                    connections.Add(connectionId);
                }
            }
        }


        public string UserNameHiddenField(string UserName)
        {
            return UserName;
        }



        public int GetAllConnections()
        {
            int quantity = 0;

            lock (_connections)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<T, HashSet<string>> comp in _connections)
                {
                    quantity++;
                }

                Debug.Write(quantity);
            }

            return quantity;

        }



        //Obtém conexões de um dedeterminado usuário
        public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T key)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return connections;
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }

        public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    return;
                }

                lock (connections)
                {
                    connections.Remove(connectionId);

                    if (connections.Count == 0)
                    {
                        _connections.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My webConfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/p/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/p/TarefasProcessos.aspx" protection="All" timeout="600" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Whats the best way to retrieve HttpContext.Current.User.Identity inside the chatHub ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `HttpContext.Current`. The user should be available on the Context object within the Hub